# how can i set radiobutton list in asp.net using eval function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I use this code for radio button using eval function...
i want to use eval function for radiobutton in asp.net
i dnt get ans from this code
thank you

```
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("gender") %>' runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="MALE" Text="MALE"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="FEMALE" Text="FEMALE"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Why is Eval function needed here? Are you bringing the data from DB or some other source?

Comment: You could bind it from server side code...!!!!

Comment: @smilu  but i want from client side code.... n yes i bring data from db.

Comment: and i update code above....plz check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using  `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("gender") %>'`

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("gender") %>' runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="MALE" Text="MALE"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="FEMALE" Text="FEMALE"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a blank field. because at page initialisation time, you may need to show the gender as unselected mode. then you can choose Male/Female.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("gender") %>' runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display: none" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="MALE" Text="MALE"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="FEMALE" Text="FEMALE"></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```